# Use Apache Tiles

Tags: apache, jsp, struts, tiles

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am working on a project that is in production for over one year, the application server is running the J2EE 1.3 version.Now i am trying to use the apache tiles framework to separate the content from the layout.The project has in the WEB-INF/lib the following libraries that implement the STRUTS framework 
 -struts1.2.6
 -struts-core-1.3.10
 -struts-extras-1.3.10.jar
 -struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar

After this introduction my nightmare begun:
1) To configure the Tiles i added the following code to my struts-config.xml:

```
<action path="/tilesTest"  
        parameter="aDef" 
        type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" />

<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" />

   <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tilesdefs.xml" />
     <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
   </plug-in>
```

The 'aDef' parameter is defined in the tilesdefs.xml.
When i call the action in the browser, it throws me the following exception:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts.config.ForwardConfig.getContextRelative()Z
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:289)**

After investigation i found a post saying the following :

*Checked the application lib folder to find struts-core-1.3.8.jar as well as struts.jar. It is because of this that the exception was thrown.
struts.jar has the forwardConfig class and getContextRelative() method.
struts-core-1.3.8.jar has the forwardConfig class , but not the getContextRelative() method.
This was causing the issue.
Therefore remove struts.jar so that 1.3.8 version is used.
-- Additionally add struts-extras-1.3.8.jar to the application lib*

Like i told in the begging i have the same two libs, the only problem is, it is the struts.jar lib that have the tiles package, the struts-core-1.3.8 do not have that package.
So what i am suppose to do , to run tiles in this application ?

Sorry for the question extension but i have to explain the all situation.
Best regards 
THANKS IN ADVANCE to anyone that tries to help me

Comment: What version of Tiles are you trying to run? Why are you trying to combine Struts 1.2.6 and Struts 1.3.10?! First, pick a version of Struts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your classpath. It doesn't make much sense to have two different versions of Struts in the classpath. The tiles classes for Struts 1.3.10 are in struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar bundled with struts-1.3.10.